# mpdf table breaks into 100+ pages

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to print some brackets through mpdf.
But when i try to print a bracket with quite a few players it breaks my table and the whole pdf and makes it with more than 100 pages. ( 1 or less tr in each page )

If however i use `page-break-inside:avoid` the table gets shrinked and printed in 1 page.

Page's size is not a fact, i even tried A2 but still 100+ pages.
`tr` and `td` are all closed fine so no issue there.

I want to break the pdf into pages but not 100++.

Anyone experienced the same issue ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in `<div>` instead of `<table>`